# How to fix white dock and title bar on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, themes, 17.10

So here's how the desktop looked after fresh install: [Desktop 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7BZl.jpg).
After restarting the system, however, it turned to this: [Desktop 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRtNG.png).
I tried tweaking the themes and icons using GNOME tweak tool but to no avail. How do I fix this?